# Sybase - Split delimited column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm still new to SQL and I was wondering if there is a way to split a delimited column into multiple rows.

```
Here's my table:
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     Name         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         | a##b##c##d       |
|---------------------|------------------|

Expected output:
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          ID         |     Name         |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          12         | a                |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          12         | b                |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          12         | c                |
    |---------------------|------------------|
    |          12         | d                |
    |---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: IMHO -- It would be **far** simpler to use a scripting language (like PHP or Python)  to parse the Name value (IE `PHP`s  `explode()` ) out, loop through the array and insert  --  Then delete the original value.  The SQL you are looking for is going to be uber complex compared to the 15 or so lines of a scripting language.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that IF `ID` is a Primary Key -- Any Approach won't work as they can't be duplicates.

Comment: unfortunately I can't use a scripting language and for this particular case I don't need a primary key

Comment: While Sybase may very well be able to do what you are asking (I am not a sybase user), it shouldn't be the job of the database to be handling this kind of a task as it is no longer set based. This is a job for a reporting service (such as SSRS or Crystal Reports or something) or a programming language. Having data of this nature means that the database schema is incorrect for the data that it is storing.

Comment: Which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?  what's being proposed would fall under the topic of `(un)Pivoting` ... some databases provide SQL constructs that can (un)pivot, others require some 'creativity' on behalf of the SQL coder; try running a search on `pivot` ... you should find a lot of references that may give you some ideas ...